# How do I retain a file's formatting when passing its data into a string?

Tags: c++, file, text, formatting

Example:

Test.xml:

```
<Test>
    This is a test.
</Test>
```

This is the code that would read in each line and add it to a "file" string:

```
std::ifstream infile("Test.xml");
if (infile.is_open()) {
    while (!infile.eof()) {
        std::getline(infile, buffer); // "buffer" variable was created before-hand
        file += buffer;
    }
}
```

But when I output the "file" string it comes out as:

```
<Test>    This is a test </Test>
```

When I need it to retain its formatted properties.

I'm curious to know if there is a way that, when reading a file, it would be able to keep the tabs and newlines as "\t" and "\n" respectively and insert them into the string?

Comment: Do you want the output to look exactly like the input, or do you want it to have tab and newline characters replaced by the strings `\t` and `\n` respectively? As in `<Test>\n\tThis is a test.\n</Test>`

Answer (score 1):

The call to `getline` removes the new line.  So you could just add it back.

```
file += buffer;
file += '\n';
```

Also, your loop condition is wrong.  The `eof` bit is not set until you try to read, and then fail because you've reached the end of the file.  This means you will add the last line twice.  You should change your loop condition to this instead:

```
while (std::getline(infile, buffer))
```

Or, you could do this instead of using a loop, to read the whole file in one shot:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << infile.rdbuf();
file = oss.str();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped magnificently.

Answer (score 1):

`std::getline(infile, buffer);` won't include trailing newlines

You can use:

`file += buffer + std::string(1,'\n');`

Using this all newlines will be preserved.
The tabs and space will already be preserved with `std::getline(infile, buffer);`

Answer (score 1):

Getline() doesn't include "\n" symbol after read. Add it manually for each line.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream input("Hello\nXML\n");
    std::ostringstream output;
    output << input.rdbuf();
    std::cout << output.str();
    return 0;
}
```

The code above is a copy of content from one stream to another. (It works with any standard input/output stream)

Comment: Consider adding an explanation.